# Add "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12' to my existing Ps1

Tags: powershell

I have the following PS1 code:-

```
cd $HelperPath
    #----------------------------------------------
    # Create configuration lists in central repository in SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" 
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
```

Now i want to add `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` before calling the .exe file,, so how the final syntax should be? for example something as follow??

```
Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it"      & "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 $HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
```

Comment: Put a semi-colon `;` between the two commands

Comment: Unsure if you specifically need TLS 1.2, but I would go with `[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13` instead if your system supports it.

Comment: @Theo thanks, i wrote the following syntax `Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it"& "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ; $HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password` but got this error `The term '[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ;C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\deployments\Scripts\Helper Utilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.UpdateView.exe' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: @BoogaRoo can you please provide the exact syntax to amend my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would suggest just putting it on a line by itself above the call to the executable:

```
cd $HelperPath
    #----------------------------------------------
    # Create configuration lists in central repository in SharePoint
    #----------------------------------------------
    Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it"
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
    & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
```

If you really must have it on a single line as described in the question, you can put a semicolon between each statement:

```
Show-Message -Message "Step 1a: Create groups and adding users to it" ; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13 ; & "$HelperPath\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.exe" "true" $Username $Password
```

Also, I would suggest using TLS 1.3 if your system supports it. I've included that in the code here.

Comment: Roook will try both, but for the first syntax should i write it with out "" ?

Comment: Yes. There is no need to enclose the TLS command in quotes.